# How to center a container in the middle of a screen

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to center a text in the middle of my screen. For some reason it doesn't work. Can someone please take a look at the following index.html and explain to me what I am doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .header {
            display: flex;
            background-color: black;
            padding: 2rem;
        }

        .outer-container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
            height: 100vh;
        }
  
        .inner-container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            cursor: default;
            justify-content: center;
        }
  
        span {
            padding: .5rem;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="parent-container">
        <div class="header">Header</div>
        <div class="outer-container">
            <div class="inner-container">
              <h1>HEADING</h1>
              <span>Some text here.</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I was thinking that the flex-layout fills all available space. Since my flex-direction is "column", I was expecting the outer container to fill the entire height of my screen, but apparently that's not the case.

Update:

I have now placed my outer-container and the inner-container inside a parent-container to showcase the issue I have when setting the height of the outer-container to 100vh: As you can see, the issue is that a height of 100vh for my outer-container is now too much - the correct height would be 100vh minus the height of the header.

Comment: A document's height is the minimum height necessary to render its contents and has nothing to do with viewport height. You have to give either `<html>` or `<body>`'s `min-height: 100vh` if you don't want `<html>`'s height to ever go below viewport's height.

Answer (score 1):

add `justify-content: center;` on both containers

Comment: Hey, thx for your help! Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. Have you tried using the index.html I provided?

Comment: I just tried it, and without any change, both text is centered, so what is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Your container does not take all screen height and vertical alignment is missing. Here is codepen https://codepen.io/ignasb/pen/KKBQzjQ with vertical and horizontal alignment. I added height and alignment css properties

```
.outer-container {
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Also you might want additional styles if that scrollbar appears.

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty solution is to make the containing parent, `body`, `.outer-container` or some `.wrapper`, fill the full viewport with `height: 100%` or `100vh`, eventually subtract heights of other elements in the same container and use below CSS to center its content.

```css
   display: grid; place-items: center;
```

**snippet**

```css
/* Make sure padding/border size are part of element size */
*    { box-sizing: border-box }

body { margin: 0 } /* remove default space, causes overflow */

.parent-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    height: 100vh; /* would cause overflow with body margin */
}

/* Takes space from .parent-container */
.header {
    display: flex;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 2rem;
}

.outer-container {
    flex: 1; /* Stretch to fill available space */
    display: grid; place-items: center; /* Easy centering demo */
}

.inner-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: default;
    justify-content: center;
}

span {
    padding: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-container">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="outer-container">
        <div class="inner-container">
            <h1>HEADING</h1>
            <span>Some text here.</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hey, thx for your help! This works, but I don't really like the idea of using a view port height of 100. What happens, for example, if I decide to place both my outer- and my inner-container into another container, which contains a header, e.g. a horizontal menu, and the two containers? In that case, a height of100vh for the outer container would simply be too large, instead I would have to subtract the height of the header from the 100vh to come up with the correct height.

Comment: It's just an example, you can use any *parent* container with any `width`/`height` and center its content with `display: grid; place-items: center`. Percentages will work just as well or some odd *aspect ratio*. Crux is *any* width and height constraint. Text in a `<td>`, image in a `.card`, etc. Need to adjust my answer?

Comment: I don't know, if I explained my issue well. I have updated my question, could you open the index.html, maybe? You will see that my text is now almost centered, but not exactly, because the height of 100vh for my outer-container is just a little too much.